# Generate Settings is disabled during set me up maven repository in Artifact Repository Browser

Tags: maven, artifactory

This is not allowing me to generate maven settings file, am I missing some plugin?
[image]

Comment: In order to generate the settings file you need to select values for repositories (Releases/Snapshots... comboboxes)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did try that but its not saving my values. For example if I enter value for Releases and move to Snapshots, it does not show Releases values. I tried entering all values and those values are not being populated.

Comment: The fields on the Set Me Up screen can only have virtual repositories. Can you verify that you choose those from the dropdown list?

Answer (score 3):

Ariel's answer above alludes to the solution.

The 'Set Me Up' window only allows virtual repositories.

If you have a repository called libs-release-local, create a virtual repository called libs-release that includes libs-release-local. Do the same for libs-release-snapshot and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Something in your Maven repository setup is probably wrong.  I had to delete ALL my maven repositories and re-run the "Quick Set Up" Maven repository creation tool.  Once I did this, the "Generate" button was available.

I would export any existing artifacts/repositories before you do this though.  Unfortunately you need to remove ALL Maven repositories before you can re-run the wizard.